# make AppleScript program that listens systemwide for shortcuts

Tags: macos, events, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-snow-leopard, applescript

I'd like to create some kind of background process that listens to all keystrokes event and acts consequently (for example does some action if CMD-A is pressed while in Finder.app, or more complex things, like sequences to create shortcuts like in emacs..)

But how can I listen to keypresses systemwide on SnowLeopard?
I thought of Applescript.. but found nothing..
(I'm good at ruby too, and intended to use rb-appscript actually)

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to capture all the keystrokes system-wide, you need [CGEventTap](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventTapCreate). I don't think it's available directly to AppleScript, maybe on 10.6 you can use `AppleScriptObjC`.  Surely it should be available to Ruby via [Bridge Support](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/RubyPythonCocoa/Articles/GenerateFrameworkMetadata.html).

However, a system-wide keyboard listener would be called very often. I would suggest to code in C or Obj-C instead, which would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Service with Automator. If you want to run a ruby script, use the Run Shell Script action and select /usr/bin/ruby in the Shell: popup menu (no need for rb-appscript).

Services can be given a Keyboard Shortcut in the System Preferences -> Keyboard preference panel.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, that's simply a system shortcut that executes a script.. I want a script that listens to keystrokes to bind even the most complex key sequences to commands.