# Make ESCAPE (ESC) key close window

Tags: applescript

How do I make an application that I can make the ESC key close a window?  Or really any key (I can change if I want to).

Please help.  Thanks

Here is what I have and I can't get it to work.

```
-- close window with "ESC"

tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Finder" to activate
    key code 53

end tell

beep 3
```

Thanks!  B-

Answer (score 0):

There's a system wide shortcut (Command + W) that will close the currently activated window

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Finder" to activate
    keystroke "w" using command down
end tell
```

However, I'm not sure that this answers your question. Its impossible to use plain AppleScript to listen to system wide keyboard events. Take a look at the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176836/make-applescript-program-that-listens-systemwide-for-shortcuts) question.

Answer (score 0):

PCWiz's link should show you the way - have a look at the second answer (by ghoppe - setting keyboard shortcut to application in preferences). Just remember to save the script as application, otherwise it'll not be eligible.